# how to hide/show dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I´m new developing on .net and using jquery. I´m trying to hide/show a dropdownlist and a checkbox that I have on my page. I can hide succesfully, but when i try to show nothing happens or i get a error on my code like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/sinttuloxs.jpg/

I tried using differents forms of show without any success.

```
$("#ddListaPrecios").Show();
```

or

```
$('#ddListaPrecios').Show('slow');
```

---

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ddListaPrecios").hide();

            $("#codigoCliente").autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: getData,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    cambiaElementos(ui.item.value);
                    updateCiudades(ui.item.value);
                    updateListaVendedores(ui.item.value);
                    updateListaPrecios(ui.item.value);
                }
            });

            $("#codigoCliente").change(function() {

                if ($("#codigoCliente").val().length == 6) {
                    cambiaElementos($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateCiudades($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateListaVendedores($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateListaPrecios($("#codigoCliente").val());

                    $("#ddListaPrecios").show();

                }
            });

            $("#ddListaPrecios").change(function() {
                //window.alert($("#ddListaPrecios").val());
                changePrecio($("#ddListaPrecios").val());

            });

            $("#ddCiudad").change(function() {
                updatePuntosEntrega($("#codigoCliente").val(), $("#ddCiudad").val());

            });
        });



        <label>Lista de Precios: </label>
        <label id="lbListaPrecios"> </label>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("ddListaPrecios") %>  
       <!-- <%= Html.CheckBox("cbCambioLista") %> <label class="inline" for="cbCambioLista">Desea cambiar lista de precios?</label>  -->
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive and jquery.Show does not exist

Comment: My blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx shows this. See also See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to jquery `$("#ddListaPrecios").Show();` needs to be all lowercase like this `$("#ddListaPrecios").show();`

see the doc here http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa you should be getting a different error now because that was the cause of your screenshots error. can you setup an example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i just change to .show(), and still nothing happens, but i don´t see any error message

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa then something is wrong with what you are doing.  Can you post an example like I said in my last comment.  Or add the html and javascript you are trying to show and hide

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa that's no help.  I need the generated html not the .net code.

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa ...load the page in the browser and view the source

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa can you tell me the exact code that is having issues

Comment: $("#codigoCliente").change(function() {

                if ($("#codigoCliente").val().length == 6) {
                    cambiaElementos($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateCiudades($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateListaVendedores($("#codigoCliente").val());
                    updateListaPrecios($("#codigoCliente").val());

                    $("#ddListaPrecios").show();

                }
            });


show doesn't work

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa check out here http://jsfiddle.net/EVEAL/2/  The change function ONLY happens when you change the text in the input box and click out of it.  Are you wanting it to happen anytime that text is changed? If so change it to `keyup` instead of `change` Also it only does `$("#ddListaPrecios").show();` if there are EXACTLY 6 characters in the input box.  Are you wanting it to happen if there are 6 or more?